# Firefox Developer Tools - Highlighting elements on hover?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

Is this possible? Chrome Dev Tools and Firebug both have this feature. Firefox Dev Tools only shows elements ON CLICK, but not on hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think currently there is any option for that. But from Firefox **29** onwards this is possible.

From the docs:

> From Firefox 29, the Inspector is no longer locked on the selected element: as you move
>   the mouse around the markup in the HTML pane, the dotted border is
>   shown around the corresponding element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector#Selecting-Elements

**Demo:** (Firefox Nightly)

[image: Demo]

Comment: Thanks Rahil! Apparently Firefox 29 ships next month, so I'll just have to be patient for this feature.